# how to end dialog box(i.e propertysheet) programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to close dialog box (which is basically derived from  propertysheet class) from code. following is my code:

```
LRESULT CSettingsSheet::OnCloseSettings(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
return 0;
}
```

the issue is endDialog terminates not only dialog box but also main application window. what could be the reason for this problem?

BTW i create this dialog box in main window as follow

```
if(settingsSheet.DoModal() == IDOK)
{

}
else
{

}
```

ideally i should set this domodal value with IDCANCEL instead of calling end dialog.

Thanks,
Khurram.

Comment: graphical programming? what library/platform are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You need to send [PSM_PRESSBUTTON message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the property sheet window:

> Simulates the selection of a property sheet button. You can send this message explicitly or by using the PropSheet_PressButton macro.
>
> `PSBTN_CANCEL` - Selects the Cancel button.
>
> **`PSBTN_OK`** - Selects the OK button. This value is not valid when using the Aero wizard style (PSH_AEROWIZARD).

Answer (score 0):

The MFC has a function for this CPropertySheet::PressButton.